# How to use a token authentification from Graph API in Azure http trigger function as webhook

Tags: authentication, azure-functions, webhooks

I used this authentication to handle Graph api calls in a webhook function.

I tried other authentication samples but this was the only only one which worked with the credentials for a service principal (app permission are needed, not user permissions - so some other auth samples doesn't worked for me)

[image]

CallRecords.Read.All - Anwendung - Read all call records - Ja - Gewährt für

The credentials are saved in a keyvault.

But the problem is on massive number of calls the authentication fails
(15.000 -20.000 request/day)

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app;

AuthenticationResult result = null;
string[] scopes = null;
string data = null;

IRestResponse response = null;

// build Authenticate for getting a token
config.Authority += config.CallRecordTenantID;

app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
                                          .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
                                          .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
                                          .Build();
    
scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                      .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogInformation("Exc.:" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

After getting many request near same time the authentication crashes; how can I avoid that?

> 2022-01-31T06:51:59Z   [Information]   AADSTS900023: Specified tenant identifier 'a1ae89fb-21b9-40bf-9d82-a10ae85a2407a1ae89fb-21b9-40bf-9d82-a10ae85a2407' is neither a valid DNS name, nor a valid external domain.
>
> Trace ID: ebbb51ed-2ef1-4931-81b6-702833c93f00
> Correlation ID: cb112afc-08bf-44bb-9a8e-b0a93938f6cb
> Timestamp: 2022-01-31 06:51:55Z
>
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.HandleTokenRefreshError(MsalServiceException e, MsalAccessTokenCacheItem cachedAccessTokenItem)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Namespace1.Webhook.GetOnlyDesiredDataAfterFiltersAsync(String CallRecordId, AzFuncCallRecordsConfiguration config, ILogger log) in D:\Repos\Webhook.cs:line 518
> at Namespace1.Webhook.Run(HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log) in D:\Repos..\BWebhook.cs:line 180

So is there is no better way, for the app service (Azure function in function app) to use authentication token.

Or is there a better way to use other webhook e.g. durable functions with orchestration with the entities?

Or is there an easier solution to bind bind the service principal to the function app direct, so the auth token must not requested in code?

Or other ideas?

I hope someone can can give advice what I can do.

Thanks

Comment: Any update to the issue?

Comment: No Update. But I got the tip for a workaround . Iuse this code and save the token and the expirationtime of the token to a static var and check  token!=null and token not expired. That worked for me for massive http-triggers to avoid the above-mentioned exception.

Comment: Glad that you got a workaround to resolve the issue. Could you post that as an answer in detailed so that it would be helpful for other community members.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT: I posted my workaround here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70938066/is-it-possible-to-build-a-azure-function-which-uses-graph-api-call-and-can-handl/71078731#71078731

Comment: Glad that you resolved the issue, Please Post that answer here or close it as duplicate!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT: but it is not an answer for this question, I hope on a better way because I think it is not a soultion for production. It is only a workround to fix in development/testing-phase. Here I asked for another possiblities to avoid this. This is complete different question, so no duplicate  and it is open. I only posted it here because you asked me in comment.