# is it possible to build a azure function which uses graph api call and can handle reliable authentification on massive load?

Tags: authentication, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

According to this post

[How to use a token authentification from Graph API in Azure http trigger function as webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70935069/how-to-use-a-token-authentification-from-graph-api-in-azure-http-trigger-functio)

the azure function crashes on many triggers at same time and so if in the code the token (Graph API) is executed the token will be requested so many time there was thrown this exception.

> 2022-01-31T06:51:59Z   [Information]   AADSTS900023: Specified tenant identifier 'a1ae89fb-21b9-40bf-9d82-a10ae85a2407a1ae89fb-21b9-40bf-9d82-a10ae85a2407' is neither a valid DNS name, nor a valid external domain.
>
> Trace ID: ebbb51ed-2ef1-4931-81b6-702833c93f00
> Correlation ID: cb112afc-08bf-44bb-9a8e-b0a93938f6cb
> Timestamp: 2022-01-31 06:51:55Z
>
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.HandleTokenRefreshError(MsalServiceException e, MsalAccessTokenCacheItem cachedAccessTokenItem)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Namespace1.Webhook.GetOnlyDesiredDataAfterFiltersAsync(String CallRecordId, AzFuncCallRecordsConfiguration config, ILogger log) in D:\Repos\Webhook.cs:line 518
> at Namespace1.Webhook.Run(HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log) in D:\Repos..\BWebhook.cs:line 180

So the question is now:
Is it realizeable with azure functions because on statefull services it is possible to store the auth token to avoid requiring every time?

I hope this question will not  be seen as a duplicate, but it is 2 different questions.

if no please write the possible failure causes why it is not possible.

Comment: You can use static variables to hold tokens in memory for some time, as long as the instance stays warm.

Comment: @junas: Many thanks I got not this idea and for the token and expiration DateTime it seems to work. We use "always on" so in normal case  this the function  should be warm as you described.

Comment: @junas: it works fine better than expected,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Azure Functions you can use static variables to hold data across executions.
The variables will be specific to that instance and will be wiped if that instance is removed.

Answer (score 0):

after the comment and answer of junas I made this workaround:

Add this 2 static Vars to your class:

```
    static string AuthToken = null;
    static DateTime TokenExpDate;
```

Chekc this Vars before Aquiring the token.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app;

AuthenticationResult result = null;
string[] scopes = null;
string data = null;

IRestResponse response = null;

// build Authenticate for getting a token
config.Authority += config.CallRecordTenantID;

app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
                                          .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
                                          .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
                                          .Build();
    
scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// ask static vars if token is vaild
if (AuthToken == null || TokenExpDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
              .ExecuteAsync();

        if (result != null)
        {
            AuthToken = result.AccessToken;
            TokenExpDate = result.ExpiresOn.UtcDateTime;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Exc.:" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```